# Defining a unique group structure so that the homomorphism property holds

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve:

> Let $A' \subset A$ be a group and a subgroup. Let $\phi: A' \to A$ denote the tautological map of sets. Then $A'$ has a unique group structure for which $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.

The "tautological map of sets" seems to me that it can only be the inclusion map, or the identity map on $A$ restricted to $A'$. Working backwards, I want for $a,b \in A'$ that
$$ 
\phi(ab) = \phi(a) \phi(b)
$$
or
$$
ab = ab. 
$$
But that seems to hold regardless, just by the definition of $\phi$. By defining a "group structure," I assume I need to define the binary operation and show that it satisfies the axioms for a group. But the map seems to always be a homomorphism.

What am I missing?

UPDATED ATTEMPT (based on helpful comments from Arturo.

> Let $(A, \star)$ be a group, $(A', \bullet)$ a subgroup, $\phi: A' \to A$ the tautological inclusion map. Suppose that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. We show that $\bullet$ is the restriction of $\star$ to $A'$. For any $a,b \in A'$, we have
> $$
> \phi(a \bullet b) = \phi(a) \star \phi(b).
> $$
> By definition, $a \bullet b \in A'$, so we have $\phi(a \bullet b) = a \bullet b$, $\phi(a) = a$, and $\phi(b) = b$. Then
> $$ 
> a \bullet b = a \star b.
> $$
> Therefore, $\bullet = \star_{|A'}$, so there exists a unique group structure on $A'$ for which $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: I agree with your overall sense of the problem, although you seem to be ignoring the "uniqueness" part of the question.

Comment: The question is: is there any operation $\bullet$ on $A'$, other than the restriction of the operation on $A$, for which we could have $\phi(a\bullet b) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ for $a,b\in A'$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Though that makes sense, I thought a subgroup has to inherit its binary operation from the ambient group. So if I want to talk about a different operation, wouldn't the entire map $\phi$ be moot?

Comment: I believe that the point of the exercise is to show that the only way that the set-theoretic inclusion map can be a group homomorphism is *if* you use the inherited binary operation: there is no other operation that can make this work. Don't know what your background is, but by comparison, if $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is a subset of $X$, then $Y$ inherits a topology from $X$ that makes the inclusion map $Y\hookrightarrow X$ a continuous map/morphism of topological spaces, but there are *other* topologies you can put on $Y$ that also make that true.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Hm, do you have a hint for how one would go about proving this? The only thing that comes to mind is contradiction, but since I don't know what precisely the binary operation on $A$ is, I can't figure out how to find a contradiction. It sounds "definitional" to me, though I am surely mistaken.

Comment: You basically already have it: the left side is whatever $a\bullet b$ is, but the right side is just $ab$. So if they are always equal, then $a\bullet b = ab$ for all $a,b\in A'$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Where does the distinction come in, though? What you're describing seems to be a direct proof that starts with letting $\phi$, the set-theoretic inclusion map, be a homomorphism. It would need to surely conclude that $a \bullet b = ab$, where I assume the right-hand side is the operation on $A$. Is the idea that $\phi(a) \phi(b)$ uses the standard operation on $A$, while the operation on the left-hand side is "to be determined"?

Comment: Yes. Suppose $\bullet$ is a binary operation on $A'$ that (i) makes $A'$ into a group under $\bullet$, *and* (ii) makes the inclusion map $\phi\colon A'\to A$ a group homomorphism. We aim to show that $a\bullet b=ab$ for all $a,b\in A'$. This will prove that the inherited operation from $A$ is the *only* group operation you can put on $A'$ that makes $\phi$ a group homomorphism. Again, this may seem silly/trivial in this context, but there are slight variations of this context where it wouldn't be a silly thing to establish.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This was extremely helpful. Would you mind taking a look at my updated attempt? I believe I understand it now. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you. One last question: by "group structure," does it just mean set and its binary operation? I would think that includes properties like commutativity, order, etc., but all of those are inherited from the binary operation.

Comment: "Group structure" means a set together with a binary operation that makes into a group. As opposed to the set structure, which is just the underlying set. (Depending on your context... if you are doing Universal Algebra, then "group structure" means a set, a binary operation corresponding to multiplication, a unary operation corresponding to multiplicative inverses, and a nullary operation corresponding to the identity element, which satisfies the relevant axioms to turn it into a group).