# Possible error in a problem statement

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I believe there is an error in this problem statement.

> Let $A' \subset A$ be a group and a subgroup. Let $\phi: A' \to A$ denote the tautological map of sets. Then $A'$ has a unique group structure for which $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.

I believe the problem statement should say let $A$ be a group and $A'$ a *subset* of $A$, which is a group in its own right. A subgroup, by definition, should inherit its operation from $A$. I can't think of any other way to define a subgroup. The definition I'm working with is that a subset $A' \subset A$ is a subgroup if (1) for all $a_1, a_2 \in A'$, $a_1 \cdot a_2 \in A'$; (2) $1_A \in A'$ (where $1_A$ is the identity in $A$); and (3) for all $a \in A'$, the element $a^{-1}$ also belongs to $A'$.

Since this definition refers directly to the operation $\cdot$ on $A$, I think the operation on a subgroup $A'$ can only be the operation on $A$ restricted to the subgroup. If I rephrase the problem to requiring only that $A'$ be a subset but with some group structure, the problem boils down to proving that the inclusion map is a homomorphism if and only if $A'$ has the composition law induced by $A'$. If $\phi$ is in fact a homomorphism, then $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) \phi(b)$ for all $a,b \in A'$. Then $a \star b = a b$, where the right-hand side is the operation on $A$ and the left-hand side is the operation on $A'$.

Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: But not every subset of a group can be regarded as a subgroup though (the tautological map is injective). Think about Lagrange's Theorem for example. More subtlely, when we forgot a group structure of a subgroup, one can construct a group structure on that underlying set but has absolutely no reason to coincide with the original structure (e.g. the SET $K_4$ can be equipped with a group structure to turn it into $\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: There is no error in this problem statement.

Comment: All that said, the statement is correct: in short, you can't have any group structure other than the subgroup structure to turn that map into a homomorphism

Comment: @Ray But I thought the statement goes deeper than that. Can I have a group structure on $A'$ at all that makes it a subgroup of $A$ that isn't the law of composition inherited from $A$? This almost seems inherited from the definition of a subgroup.

Comment: @MathNewbie No, a group structure on $A'$ making it a subgroup of $A$ is, tautologically, the subgroup structure. The statement in the post says the following: if one forgets the group structure of $A'$, then any group structure one imposes on $A'$ (regarded as a set now) making $\phi$ a group homomorphism is necessary the subgroup structure.

Comment: Excellent, that makes far more sense. Would I be correct then that the first line of a proper proof should be a statement of "existence" to the effect of, "certainly $A'$ is a subgroup with law of composition inherited from $A$," and then proceed to uniqueness?

Comment: There is a discussion of this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322276/defining-a-unique-group-structure-so-that-the-homomorphism-property-holds)